# Update specific field of Object using Builder in java

Tags: java, builder, lombok

I have two class with me as mentioned below.
I wanted to create two instances of **`class A`**.

I want to create instance obj2 from existing instance obj1 with updated value of a3 attribute as **`"Java"`**.

I had tried below line using **Builder**, but it's not working.

```
A obj2 = obj1.builder().a3("Java").build();
```

I am able to do it with calling constructor, but I wanted to do it **`Builder`** pattern only.

```
@Builder
@Data
class A {
    String a1;
    String a2;
    String a3;
    B b;

    A(String b1, String b2, String b3, B b) {
        this.a1 = b1;
        this.a2 = b2;
        this.a3 = b3;
        this.b = b;
    }
}

@Builder
@Data
class B {
    String b1;
    String b2;
    String b3;

    B(String b1, String b2, String b3) {
        this.b1 = b1;
        this.b2 = b2;
        this.b3 = b3;
    }

}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        B b = new B("a", "b", "b");
        A obj1 = new A("a1", "b1", "b1", b);
        A obj2 = new A("x1", "y1", "z1", b);
List<A> list= new ArrayList<>();
list.add(obj1);
list.add(obj2);
list.forEach(a -> {a.toBuilder().a1("newA1").a2("newA2").build()});

        A obj3 = obj1.toBuilder().a3("Java").build();
    }
}
```

}
}

As mentioned in updated code , i have list of A with me, and i want to update **`a1 and a2`** attributes of all element in list using builder. But builder is not working fine with lambda.
If i will use setter with below code it's working fine.

```
list.forEach(a -> {
a.setA1("newA1");
a.setA2("newA2");
});
```

I am not able to get updated values for **`a1 and a2`** in case of **`Builder`** with **`Lambda`**

Comment: `@Builder` from lombok is used only to instantiate an object. Besides `builder` is a static method, you cannot invoke it on an object instance.

Comment: @Andronicus I am able to invoke `obj1.builder().a3("Java").build()`. But problem is that only that attribute `a3` is set and all remaining fields are `null`. Even though those fields are there in `obj1`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`obj1.builder()` is an allowed but confusing way to say `A.builder()`. It's not recommended to call a static method on an instance. Either way, a completely new `A` will be created.

```
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
```

might be what you are looking for

> If true, generate an instance method to obtain a builder that is initialized with the values of this instance. Legal only if `@Builder` is used on a constructor, on the type itself, or on a static method that returns an instance of the declaring type.
>
> ```
> boolean toBuilder() default false;
> ```

Comment: I am okay that new `A` get created, but i want all values of other attributes of `old object`.

Comment: Hello Mate, I am facing issue with lambda expression with @Builder pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you have to enable `toBuilder()` in the annotation. `toBuilder()` allows you to edit the current object.

```java
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
```

and then doing `obj1.toBuilder().a3("Java").build()` should work.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can update the fields in existing object using lombok Builder method.
As few people suggested about `toBuilder = true`, it creates completely new object but doesn't update the existing object.

Only way is using `@Setter` annotation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).